# Stop "Welcome To Office" screen from appearing

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office-2013

[image: Welcome to Office dialog]

A “Welcome to Office” window keeps popping up randomly days apart asking me to sign in. I want it to go away and I never and have never gone online when I use Office 2013 For Students (actually I only use Word 2013). As far as I know it started after a recent update to Office 2013.

---

**Update: 10/29**

I went through Settings > Apps & Features (old Add/Remove Programs) and see a colorful icon for my Microsoft Office Home & Student 2013 which I installed, but farther down the in the list I see another gray icon for something called Office that is only 1.67 MB in size. Could that smaller gray Office program be the problem? I wonder if it was something the Windows 10 Cumulative Update back in August decided to push on me.
[image]

Comment: If the problem happened after an recent update to Office 2013, please specify, the update in question.

Comment: I wish I could, but I just know one day it started popping up and then I looked and saw a few Office 2013 updates had been installed not too long beforehand, and I wasn't really that aware Office was still updating. Heck, the Windows 10 Cumulative Update installed in the middle of August without my permission. I found the dialog was appearing in September. Today it interrupted a game I was playing.

Comment: Yes, you need to remove the 1.67 MB Office (365)

Answer (score 0):

I found how to get rid of it, you have kiosk mode enabled.
First you have to log in with your account, to do that you have to press Ctrl+Alt+Super ( <kbd>**⊞**</kbd> ).

When you get to your desktop you have to click the Windows logo, go to *Configuration* -> *Accounts* -> *Other users*. You will see the kiosk settings at the bottom, click it and disable it or delete all the users you see there.